# FCM for NodeJS server

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm reading documentation about FCM for NodeJS [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message). But I don't know what to write in npm install? How to import FCM in Node JS? I have to send notifications to users with socket. Thank you.

Comment: You set up the Admin SDK to send messages.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

Answer (score 0):

For sending notification from nodejs using Firebase you have to install firebase-admin package :

```
$ npm install firebase-admin --save
```

Comment: This is the set up for the web client SDK.  The OP is asking about the Admin SDK for server side work, which is a different thing.